# Return the taxonomy key rather than description

Tags: bolt-cms

I have a taxonomy type that looks like the below:

```
packages:
    slug: packages
    singular_slug: package
    behaves_like: grouping
    options: { unsupported: "Unsupported Description", supported: "Supported Description" }
    has_sortorder: true
    listing_template: listing_packages.twig
```

Is it possible to output the option key rather than the value from within my template? When I'm using the "packages/unsupported" url, {{ slug }} currently outputs "Unsupported Description" rather than "unsupported" which is fine, except I need both.

I was hoping to have some custom blocks within my listing template based on the slug i.e.

```
{% setcontent block = "block/" ~ slug %}
```

...but obviously it'd be better in this case to use key rather than value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the keys (for some reason this only worked when I initialised the option_key variable first):

```
{% set option_key = '' %}
{% for key, value in taxonomy.options %}
    {% if value == slug %}
        {% set option_key = key %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% setcontent block = "block/" ~ option_key %}
```